# Inconsistent interface of Pandas Series; yielding access to underlying data

Tags: pandas

While the new Categorical Series support since pandas 0.15.0 is fantastic, I'm a bit annoyed with how they decided to make the underlying data inaccessible except through underscored variables. Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.empty(3, dtype=np.int64)

s = pd.DatetimeIndex(x, tz='UTC')

x
Out[17]: array([140556737562568,        55872352,              32])

s[0]
Out[18]: Timestamp('1970-01-02 15:02:36.737562568+0000', tz='UTC')

x[0] = 0

s[0]
Out[20]: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')

y = s.values

y[0] = 5

x[0]
Out[23]: 5

s[0]
Out[24]: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000005+0000', tz='UTC')
```

We can see that both in construction and when asked for underlying values, no deep copies are being made in this DatetimeIndex with regards to its underlying data. Not only is this potentially useful in terms of efficiency, but it's great if you are using a DataFrame as a buffer. You can easily get the numpy primitive containing the underlying data, from there get a pointer to the raw data, which some low level C routine can use to do a copy into from some block of memory.

Now lets look at the behavior of the new Categorical Series. The underlying data of course is not the levels, but the codes.

```
x2 = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.int64)

s2 = pd.Categorical.from_codes(x2, ["hello", "bye"])

s2
Out[27]: 
[hello, hello, hello]
Categories (2, object): [hello, bye]

x2[0] = 1

s2[0]
Out[29]: 'hello'

y2 = s2.codes

y2[0] = 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-0366d645c98d> in <module>()
----> 1 y2[0] = 1

ValueError: assignment destination is read-only

y2 = s2._codes

y2[0] = 1

s2[0]
Out[34]: 'bye'
```

The net effect of this behavior is that as a developer, efficient manipulation of the underlying data for Categoricals is not part of the interface. Also as a user, the from_codes constructor is slow as it deep copies the codes, which may often be unnecessary. There should at least be an option for this.

But the fact that codes is a read only variable and _codes needs to be used strikes me as worse. Why wouldn't .codes give the same behavior as .values? Is there some justification for this beyond the concept that the codes are "private"? I'm hoping some of the pandas gurus on stackoverflow can shed some light on this.

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the place to complain about this, it's better to post an issue at [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) about your complaint

Comment: I considered that, sorry if my post comes across more as complaint, the goal is to understand the considerations of the devs that I may be missing. If nobody here can shed light on this, then I will continue to something like that.

Comment: I'm sure they will answer this it's just that I think that this domain knowledge is so specific to the pandas devs that it's something that probably is better served on their repository, I've not voted to close or anything, others may also be interested or feel the same as you so it may be a valid question for SO but others may not feel the same. Hopefully you'll get an answer soon.

Comment: Thanks EdChum for your positivity, it's appreciated. If nothing bubbles up in the next couple of days I'll take it as a sign and close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Categorical` type is different from almost all other types in that it is a compound type that has a certain guarantee among its data. Namely that the codes provide a factorization of the levels.

So the argument against mutability is that it would be easy to break the codes-categories mapping, and it could be non-performant. Of course these could possibly be mitigated with checking on the setitem instead (but with some added code complexity).

The vast majority of users are not going to manipulate the codes/categories directly (and only use exposed methods) so this is really a  protection against accidently breaking these guarantees.

If you need to efficiently manipulate the underlying data, best/easiest is simply to pull out the codes/categories. Mutate them, then create a new Categorical (which is cheap if codes/categories are already provided).

e.g.

```
In [3]: s2 = pd.Categorical.from_codes(x2, ["hello", "bye"])

In [4]: s2
Out[4]: 
[hello, hello, hello]
Categories (2, object): [hello, bye]

In [5]: s2.codes
Out[5]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int8)

In [6]: pd.Categorical(s2.codes+1,s2.categories,fastpath=True)
Out[6]: 
[bye, bye, bye]
Categories (2, object): [hello, bye]
```

Of course this is quite dangerous, if you added 2 to the expression would blow up. Manipulation of the codes directly is simply buyer-be-ware.

Comment: This code is very odd to me, I'm on pandas 0.15.0 unfortunately and not 0.15.2 and can't easily switch. The standard constructor takes the values, not the codes, so I'm not sure how that worked out. Nor do I have the fastpath option, nor is it documented: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.categorical.Categorical.html. Can you shed any light on how that worked out?

Comment: see the code here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/categorical.py. this the internal way of calling the constructor. fastpath is an internal argument as well.